# HttpClient Post sends a null content

Tags: java, c#, servlets, dotnet-httpclient

I am tryng to send a post request on HttpClient in C# to a java servlet engine but the server receives a Null cotnent. Client is C3 and Server is Java servlet engine. The request reaches server but errors out on null cotnent.

C# Code that sends the buffer

```cs
string loginBuffer = "test";
HttpClient hClient = GetClient();
using StringContent loginString = new StringContent(loginBuffer, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/text");
 var response1 = await hClient.PostAsync(new Uri("https://sampleserver.com/Login"), loginString);
```

**Server Code that finds a null content in reading the get ReqiestBar
**

```java
    protected StringBuffer getRequestBuffer(ServletRequest request) throws IOException 
    {
        StringBuffer sb = null;
        try
        {
            sb = new StringBuffer();
            BufferedReader br = request.getReader();
            String line = new String();
            line = br.readLine();
```

The same servlet works when connecting from a VBA code

```vb
Dim res As String res = "" 

If req Is Nothing Then 

        Set req = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest 

End If 

req.SetTimeouts 1800000, 1800000, 1800000, 1800000 m_serverURL = 

getserverurl req.Open "POST", m_serverURL & "/" & Service, False 

req.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", "" & VBA.Len(buffer) 

req.setRequestHeader "X-client", "WinExcel" 

req.Send buffer
```

Comment: How have you verified that the issue is on the C# side?

Comment: I have another vba client that is working ok on the same servlet.

Comment: I get a 200K response back and I see the request has reached the server but the servlet is not able to get any content.

Comment: Then use a tool like Telerik's Fiddler to compare the requests made by .NET and VBA, see what's different, and then modify your C# code to match. .NET's HttpClient is for sure sending `loginString`, so it seems like the servlet is expecting something else. Perhaps it expects form-encoded data, or a multipart content request. And perhaps also show your working VBA code?

Comment: Dim res As String
    res = ""
    If req Is Nothing Then
        Set req = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    End If
    req.SetTimeouts 1800000, 1800000, 1800000, 1800000
    m_serverURL = getserverurl       
    req.Open "POST", m_serverURL & "/" & Service, False
    req.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", "" & VBA.Len(buffer)
    req.setRequestHeader "X-client", "WinExcel"      
    req.Send buffer

Comment: You can (and should) edit your question.

Comment: I just realised your MIME type in C# is wrong. It should be `text/plain` not `application/text`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```cs
string loginBuffer = "test";
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        
string url = "https://sampleserver.com/Login";
StringContent loginString = new StringContent(loginBuffer, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, loginString);
```

Comment: A tiny bit of text explanation on how your answer solves the issue is always useful

Comment: Hi, I tried what you suggested but did not work. Appreciate your input.